# Difference between compiler creating default constructor and user creating default constructor in case of inheritance

Tags: c++

I would like to know the exact difference of both of the following codes. I am clear that if i am creating an object of Derived class both of the program will throw error. That is happening because the constructor of base class is private.

I am using the following version of gcc
gcc version 4.8.3 20140627 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 212064] (SUSE Linux)

Please let me know why the first program not showing any error in compilation time. But the second one shows the error in compilation.

```
No error
****************************************
class Base
{
    private:
    Base()     
    {
         cout << "Base constructor" << endl;    
    }
};
class Derived:public Base
{
};
int main()
{
    return 0;
}


Throwing Error at compilation time
*****************************************
class Base
{
    private:
    Base()
    {
         cout << "Base constructor" << endl;
    }
};
class Derived:public Base
{
    public:
    Derived()
    {
    }
};
int main()
{
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: One difference between a compiler generated constructor and a user defined one (even an empty one) is that the compiler generated one is [trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Trivial_default_constructor) whereas a user defined one never is.

Answer (score 3):

The default constructor that is implicitly declared by the compiler for the first `Derived` is defined as deleted; a compilation error will occur if you try to use that constructor. The constructor that is explicitly declared in the second `Derived` attempts to call the private base constructor, so the definition itself is ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments....I would like to know even if we are not creating the object then also Derived attempts to call the private base constructor. What do you mean by defined as deleted for the first Derived.

Comment: @user2390140 It's the compiler's responsibility to ensure that your code follows the rules of the C++ language. One of those rules is that access to private names is forbidden outside the class to which they belong. Even if you do not create a `Derived` object in `main`, some other translation unit might.

Comment: @user2390140 "Defined as deleted" means that the function is defined as though its definition were `= delete;`. Any attempt to odr-use the function will result in a compilation error.